# How to make find-file-other-window reuse existing window

Tags: window, files, find-file

Is it possible to make `find-file-other-window` open the file in a pre-existing window instead of creating a new one?

Currently:

```
|A---|B---|                              |A-|C-|B---|
|----|----| -> `find-file-other-window`  |--|--|----|
|----|----|                              |--|--|----|
|----|----|                              |--|--|----|
```

What I want is for the newly created file to be opening in `window B` instead of creating `window C`.

Comment: `C-x 4 b` will get you there, at least.

Comment: `C-x 4 b` doesn't work for me (Aquamacs Emacs 3.6 based on GNUEmacs 25.3.50.1) - it asks me which window I want to use, and then either opens the file in an invisible window or splits the windows as the question, neither of which is the desired behaviour.